# ¿Cómo guardar una respuesta de un formulario en una variable?

Tags: php, javascript, html, formularios

Tengo una página donde da un resultado y quiero que sea calificado por el usuario.

Entonces puse un formulario pero lo que quiero es que esa respuesta se guarde en una variable por *PHP* para luego insertarla en la base de datos al apretar un botón.

Tengo el siguiente código pero al apretar `ENVIAR` se ejecuta el `POST` y solo quiero que salga un mensaje como *Calificación enviada* sin salir de la página, ni recargala.

Código:

```html
<form class="calificanos" action="resultado.php" method="post">
  <div><h4>¿Consideras este resultado acertado?</h4></div>
  <div class="pregunta-calificanos">
  <select class="down-list-calificanos" name="calificanos">
    <option value="3">Sí</option> 
    <option value="2">No estoy seguro</option> 
    <option value="1">No</option> 
  </select>
  </div>
  <input class="boton-2" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Los formularos por defecto al hacer clic en el botón submit van a redirigirse al archivo que indiques en el **action**. Para hacer lo que pides tendrías que hacer uso de JavaScript y AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Precisamente en estos días estaba jugando con las funciones asíncronas y parece que han conseguido endulzar un poco el [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp).

He construido un dataset básico:

```
CREATE TABLE diegomedina(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  acierto int,
  instante timestamp
  );
```

Y he añadido un poco de código a tu formulario:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['acierto'])){
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','stackoverflow');
    sleep(2);
    if($conn->query("
        INSERT INTO diegomedina (acierto) VALUES (
            ".($_GET['acierto']*1)."
          );
    ")) echo json_encode([($_GET['acierto']*1)]);
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
async function enviar(){
    let url = 'http://localhost/stackoverflow/diegomedina/index.php?acierto='
        + document.getElementById('acierto').value;
    let r = await (await fetch(url,{mode:"no-cors"})).json();
    switch(r[0]){
        case 3: txt=' Nos alegra que te haya gustado'; break;
        case 2: txt=' Vaya, ¿lo intentamos de nuevo?'; break;
        case 1: txt=' Sentimos que no sea de tu agrado, tomamos nota'; break;
    }
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML=txt;
}   
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div><h4>¿Consideras este resultado acertado?</h4></div>
  <div class="pregunta-calificanos">
  <select class="down-list-calificanos" name="calificanos" id="acierto">
    <option value="3">Sí</option> 
    <option value="2">No estoy seguro</option> 
    <option value="1">No</option> 
  </select>
  <span id="feedback"></span>
  </div>
  <input class="boton-2" type="submit" onclick="enviar()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

En primer lugar, para evitar la recarga de la página, he eliminado la etiqueta `form`. Así todo se quedará en JS, concretamente en la función `enviar()` que se pondrá en marcha al pulsar sobre el botón de Enviar. Ésta simplemente invoca al backend en PHP que está alojado en el mismo fichero, y es el que se encarga de realizar el `INSERT`. Después devuelve el control al JS, confirmado que el dato ha sido correctamente registrado.

El `sleep(2)` es un retardo que he introducido artificialmente para ilustrar la interacción asíncrona. En esta [web](https://lemoncode.net/lemoncode-blog/2018/1/29/javascript-asincrono) han hecho un excelente trabajo explicándolo.

Te paso una captura del dataset a modo de comprobación de la correcta inserción de las calificaciones:

[image: Dataset]

Espero que te resulte útil. Aunque hayamos pasado por JS, finalmente hemos terminado con la variable en PHP, y el la base de datos, sin recargar la página.